# Print number of rows in each file inside a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder `D:\Arun\myfolder`. Inside this say I have 60 files. I want to know the number of rows inside each file like below: (probably written in a separate sheet)

```
 File1 - 240 rows
 File2 - 321 rows
 File3 - 178 rows
 .. 
 ..
```

So I'm trying with the below code, but it is not giving me any output. I have very little knowledge in `VBA` and I'm not sure why the below code is not working.

```
Sub CountRows()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbXLS As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String
    Dim NbRows As Integer, rg As Range
    DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sPath = "D:\Arun\myfolder"       'Path of XLS Files
    sFilename = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")
    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
        If sFilename <> ThisWorkbook.FullName Then
            Set wbXLS = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFilename)           'open file
            NbRows = wbXLS.Sheets(1).Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Row  'nb of rows
            Set rg = wb.Worksheets("Check").Range("A60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            rg = sFilename
            rg.Offset(0, 1) = NbRows
            wbXLS.Close False   'close file
        End If
        sFilename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, your path needs a backslash at the end... and remove `On Error Resume Next` so you can see the errors and troubleshoot them. Use F8 to step through the code. Set breakpoints. Check variables as you go.

Comment: Also I can see that You're doing `rg = sFilename` and the line below You are trying to "offset" the Filename with `rg.Offset(0, 1) = NbRows`, it rather won't work.

Comment: After testing your issue seems to be this: `sFilename = Dir(sPath & "*.xls")` doesn't return anything, because it strings the filename to the end of your folder name, which obviously doesn't exist. Change it to `sFilename = Dir(sPath & "\" & "*.xls")`.

Comment: @braX  Done. I have added the backslash and removed `On Error Resume Next`. It is not showing any error as well.

Comment: @Plutian , i have tried changing the line that you have mentioned. But still it is same. No output.

Comment: Line `Set wbXLS = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFilename)` has the same issue. `Set wbXLS = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFilename)`

Comment: Set a breakpoint (F9) at `Do While Len(sFilename) > 0` and check your variables, use F8 to step line by line to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA has methods that make looping through files much easier. Try looping all the .xls files in your folder like this

```
Sub count_rows()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb, wbXLS As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook   'the workbook where you output the data must be active when you run the macro

Dim objFSO As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim myfolder As Object
Set myfolder = objFSO.GetFolder("INSERT YOUR FOLDER PATH HERE") 'sets the folder where you have the .xls files to loop

For Each objFil In myfolder.Files
    i = i + 1
    If InStr(1, objFil.name, ".xls") > 0 Then  'you make sure you are only working with .xls files inside your folder
        Set wbXLS = Workbooks.Open(objFil.Path)
        NbRows = wbXLS.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Row   'this will count all the cells in column A (it doesn't discriminate blank cells)
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(objFil.name, ".xls", "")
        wb.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = NbRows
        wbXLS.Close False
        Set wbXLS = Nothing
    End If
Next objFil

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Just an observation. `Dim wb, wbXLS As Workbook`. In that line, only `wbXLS` is being defined as `Workbook`. Variable `wb`, because there is no data/object type specified, is being defined as `Variant`. I think it should be `Dim wb as Workbook, wbXLS As Workbook`. Also `wb.Sheets.Cells`, you don't specify a sheet. It should be something like `wb.Sheets(1).Cells` or `wb.ActiveSheet.Cells`. Also `wbXLS.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells.Count` will return cell count, not row count as OP wants

Comment: @Pablo G, i'm getting `run time error 438`. this property not supported in the line `wb.Sheets.Cells(i, 1).Value = Replace(objFil.Name, ".xls", "")`

Comment: Make sure that when you run the macro, you are setting wb with the workbook where you want to output the data. I edited in the answer a comment line. Or else, how is the name of the file where you need the output data?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, you are right. I missed adding Sheets(1), so it was throwing an error